# How to convert ros packages into c++ code to be used in code blocks?

Tags: ros, c++, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have several ros packages running, but i need to convert all into a c++ codes but how do i do it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11145/how-to-convert-ros-packages-into-c++-code-to-be-used-in-code-blocks?/) by [cheyanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/1055/cheyanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-09-07**:
Can you be more specific? What do you mean by convert several packages into C++ code? Do you mean transforming a multi-processes application into a single process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS nodes are just executables which can be run from the terminal or CodeBlocks. You will need to figure out how to set environment variables inside Code Blocks, but if you can do that you should not have a problem launching any of the c++ executables from within CodeBlocks.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you asking ["how to create a ROS package using CodeBlocks"](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#CodeBlocks)?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cheyanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/1055/cheyanne/) on 2011-09-09**:
I meant running the packages in codeblocks form instead of using the terminals in linux. Because I'm quite new to this and I actually tried the http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#CodeBlocks but I thought this is not I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To edit a ROS package using CodeBlocks, one can generate the project file using cmake:

```
roscd <your_package>
mkdir build_codeblocks 
cd build_codeblocks 
cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" ..
```

According to http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Generator_Specific_Information ,
you need cmake version at least 2.6.

Start CodeBlocks from Terminal directly  rather than click on the app launcher.
In this way, codeblocks will inherit all ROS_* variable from bash shell.

Then open the your_package.cbp using CodeBlocks. You should be able to compile without any problem.

When Run, remember to choose the right target, <your_pacakge> not the default "all"

HTH

---

Originally posted by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) with karma: 91 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2